# Coinbase Pro Fees and Total

Tags: php, laravel, api, coinbase-api

I have wondered on how the Coinbase get / calculate its Fees and total upon inputting a value in the Order (Market, Limit, Stop). Can anyone explain how to get the Fees and Total or maybe there's a coinbase api to be used in this one? It would really be a big help. Thank you! Here's the attached screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read more about the Coinbase fees [here](https://help.coinbase.com/en/coinbase/trading-and-funding/pricing-and-fees/fees).

At this moment, Coinbase trading fee is 0.2%.

```
Fee: 0.2% of 20 is: 0.04
Total: 20 - 0.04 = 19.96 GBP / 10601.60 GBP = 0.00188273468 BTC
*10601.60: is BTC market price
```

Comment: this calculation goes around for the limit and stop order also?

Comment: Yes, the limit and stop order is set at a specific BTC price, so it will calculate at that price.

Comment: noted, thanks and btw I have accepted your answer already. :)